# Jsoup Element.wrap(String html) method throwing NullPointerException

Tags: jsoup

I currently have code that wraps a Table around an Element:

```java
public static Element wrapElementInTable(Element e)
{
    if (e == null)
        return null;
    return e.wrap(createTableTemplate().outerHtml());
}

public static Element createTableTemplate()
{
    return createElement("table", "").appendChild( 
                createElement("tr").appendChild(
                createElement("td"))
           );
}
```

Now I create an Element in my main method:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    Element e = new Element(Tag.valueOf("span"),"");
    String text = HtmlGenerator.wrapElementInTable(e).outerHtml();
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

The problem is I receive a NullPointerException in the wrap method for apparently no reason.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jsoup.nodes.Node.wrap(Node.java:345)
at org.jsoup.nodes.Element.wrap(Element.java:444)
at usingjsoup.HtmlGenerator.wrapElementInTable(HtmlGenerator.java:56)
at usingjsoup.UsingJsoup.main(UsingJsoup.java:19)
Java Result: 1
```

Does anyone know why a NullPointerException is being thrown? (If I print out the element before I call wrap the output is the tag I created)

Comment: Check your createElement(String,String) method.

Comment: My createElement method is basically a helper method that calls: return new Element(Tag.valueOf(tag),baseUri).appendText("");

Comment: what is the baseUri? is it null?

Comment: baseUri is "". The problem is if I output the element before I call wrap I get the tag that I created.

Comment: Regardless of my code this following code throws a NullPointerException:  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Element e = new Element(Tag.valueOf("p"), "");
        Element e2 = new Element(Tag.valueOf("div"), "");
        e.wrap(e2.outerHtml());
        System.out.println(e);
    } Am I not using the wrap method correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got you the answer, the NPE is thrown since you don't have the parentNode. Jsoup tries to do the wrap without checking for null value in the parentNode as below

```
  //the below line throws NPE since parentNode is null
  parentNode.replaceChild(this, wrap);
```

So, you **cannot** wrap Element with **input html String** without **parentNode**. In this way, you can do the wrap `<p>` with `<div>` with the document (parentNode)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document document = Jsoup.parse("<p>");
        Element p = document.select("p").first();
        Element div = document.createElement("div");
        p.replaceWith(div);
        div.appendChild(p);
        System.out.println(document);
    }
```

The output would be

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <p></p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps